# If something is provable in ZFC, can ZFC prove that ZFC proves it?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

IF ZFC proves a Well-formed formula, it means,

if  $ZFC \vdash \phi$,

then, $ZFC \vdash (ZFC \vdash \phi$) ?

Generally, if an axiom system proves a wff, the axiom system can prove that it proves the fomula?

Comment: The statement "$ZFC\vdash\phi$" is a $\Sigma^0_1$ arithmetical formula, and ZFC proves every true $\Sigma^0_1$ formula. This property is known as $\Sigma^0_1$ completeness and not all axioms systems have it, but the most common ones (even the weak ones, like Robinson's Q) do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not conversely.

If $T$ is a recursive theory that is strong enough to internalise FOL via the standard methods,<sup>1</sup> then all "real" statements in the language of $T$ get coded via standard codes, and all proofs are of finite length which lets us code real proofs in a way that is compatible with the internalisation of FOL.

You can prove this easily by induction on the complexity of the formula, that a standard formula gets assigned a standard code, and then by the definition of the provability predicate.

If $T$ is not recursive, you will need an oracle for it anyway, but the above arguments apply.

Note that in the other direction of the implication, if $T$ is consistent but actually proves $\lnot\operatorname{Con}(T)$, then $T$ does not *prove* $0=1$, but it proves that it proves $0=1$ (because the internal proof is not standard anymore).

---

1. Note that in PA this means Gödel codes, but in ZFC we can actually code things via finite strings as objects in $V_\omega$ instead. This makes more intuitive sense, and if you know that $V_\omega$ is "essentially $\omega$", then you can move between Gödel codes and actual finite sequences freely enough.

Comment: +1. Quickly clarifying for the OP: when Asaf says "Yes, but not conversely," he doesn't mean that *it is known that* there is a sentence which ZFC doesn't prove but does prove that it proves; rather, he means that *it is in principle possible* for ZFC to be consistent and yet prove that it proves a sentence which in fact it doesn't prove. It is generally believed that this doesn't in fact happen (similarly to how it's generally believed that ZFC is consistent), and many natural theories stronger than ZFC can prove that it doesn't happen (similarly to how they can prove the consistency of ZFC).